# Can I make Javascript always call a method after JQuery Load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We have started using [jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) in our site to load contents into a div rather than re-loading whole page. However in the complete function we have a method that re-applies various bindings. Is it possible to provide load method with a default complete function?  So developers don't have to specify it in the jquery load complete function.

As we currently are providing a lot of duplicate complete functions

E.g.

```
$('#Target').load(callBackRedirect, function () {
        ApplyBindings('#Target');
    });
```

These bindings can't be applied using `on` and need to be re-applied on page loads. We also do some other work that we want to do on every page load.

Comment: Why can't they be applied using on?

Comment: So you want to know what the default callback function is? Sorry it was hard to figure out what you really wanted.

Comment: I want to provide a default complete callback  function so I don't have to specify the same complete function in multiple places.

Comment: We are using kendoDatePicker which doesn't seem to let us bind with on. It is bound like ('.datep').kendoDatePicker(kendoPickerBaseOptions);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

You need the callback because that's what the method calls when the request is done.

This works with `on` method to, you might be doing something wrong out there in the code.

You could create a helper function for this.

```
function loadSomething(targetElement, uri,callback) {
    targetElement.load(uri, callback);
}

loadSomething(
    $('myElement'),
    'mylink.com/content',
    function() {
        applyBindings($(this));
    }
)
```

Comment: This isn't correct. There are [global AJAX event handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) which you can hook up to.

Comment: Yeah so not using load() directly would give us an interception point that I could put code in. Possibly a safer option than making Load() secretly do magic stuff

Comment: This is a basic example. You can implement it the way you need :P

Comment: Good solution, this can be improved by passing an object to `loadSomething` instead of parameters though.

Comment: Yep, a config object maybe or some stuff like that if it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`$.ajaxSetup`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   complete: function() {
     ApplyBindings('#target');
   }
});
```

**EDIT**

You could also make a named function like:

```
var ajaxApplyBindings = function() {
  ApplyBindings('#Target');
  // anything else...
};
```

And then pass it to `load`:

```
$('#Target').load(callBackRedirect, ajaxApplyBindings);
```

Comment: Better avoid doing so, this will create a global `complete` method for every request. Use it carefully :P

Comment: Will that apply complete to all places we are use Ajax calls?

Comment: @kappaismyname That's true. If the OP needs it to be rebinded every request then this would work. But if not, this wouldn't be the greatest solution

Comment: That probably will cause issues. We use a lot of Ajax elsewhere and not sure I want to globally replace their complete functions.

Comment: @GraemeMiller Never do that, your application will scale and cause many problems. It can be implemended but it will be a pain in the ass in the future.

Comment: @GraemeMiller Yeah like kappaismyname said it wouldn't be a good idea; see my edited answer.

Comment: Check my answer. you mostly need a helper function more than a specific one for this kinds of stuff because that is what he asked for, something not to reinvent the wheel everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Check out the list of [Global AJAX Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/).

e.g.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    alert('Triggered ajaxComplete handler.');
});
```

That said, you shouldn't need to reapply your bindings after an AJAX call. If you need to do this, you're probably doing something wrong. Check out [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which explains how to bind to content which is added dynamically.